# laravel - passing more than one list to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a list of leagues which I am passing to a view like this...

```
$leagues = League::lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('gameworlds.create')->with('leagues', $leagues);
```

What I would like to do is pass another list, for example, countries, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

e.g.

```
$leagues = League::lists('name', 'id');
$countries = Country::lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('gameworlds.create')->with('leagues', $leagues ... ... ... );
```

How can I also append $countries please?
I have see creating $data as an array, but again, not entirely sure how to set that up.

Can someone advise please?

DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, just add multiple "with" elements:

```
$leagues = League::lists('name', 'id');
$countries = Country::lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('gameworlds.create')->with('leagues', $leagues)->with('countries', $countries);
```

Comment: i have marked this as the answer because it's the one that makes most intuitive sense to me.... "just add a with for each thing you want to add" - thanks to all - I will investigate the other answers fully to understand my options. many thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

All these answers are correct but no-one's given you the nicest, easiest, most readable version:

```
// get data
$leagues = League::lists('name', 'id');
$countries = Country::lists('name', 'id');

// render view and pass data in
return View::make('gameworlds.create', compact('leagues', 'countries'));
```

Things to consider:

- PHP's [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function is very useful syntactic sugar
- I prefer passing data to my view as the second parameter to `View::make()`, but you can still do this with `->with(compact(...))`

Comment: i'll be looking into this compact function more - i didn't mark it as the answer as on this occasion i used a different solution. thanks all the same for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
 $leagues = League::lists('name', 'id');
 $countries = Country::lists('name', 'id');
 $data['leagues'] = $leagues;
 $data['countries'] = $countries;
 return View::make('gameworlds.create')->with($data);
```

Contrary to what trizz said, you can access the variables within the View from the name of the Array index. 
Means you can access them via $leagues / $countries like with multiple with statements

Comment: My bad. I've changed my answer :)

Comment: I would have commented on your answer instead of making a similar response, but it takes 50 reputation to comment

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
return View::make('gameworlds.create')
           ->with('leagues', $leagues)
           ->with('countries', $countries); // more withs could be added
```

Or this as well

```
$array = array('leagues' => $leagues, 'countries' => $countries);
return View::make('gameworlds.create', $array);
```

Or using shortcut `array` syntax

```
return View::make('gameworlds.create', ['leagues' => $leagues, 'countries' => $countries]);
```

Or using [compact](http://www.php.net/compact)

```
$leagues = League::lists('name', 'id');
$countries = Country::lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('gameworlds.create', compact('leagues', 'countries'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return View::make('gameworlds.create')->with(array('leagues'=>$leagues,'countries'=> $countries));
```